# как изменить .png с помощью блокнота

Tags: файлы, текстовые-файлы, форматы-файлов

я хочу сделать что то типа цикады 3301 только проше и меньше.
и мне нужно что бы при открытии файла .png с помощью блокнота у меня открывалось мое собщение
и при этом файл .png не изменялся и не ломался . Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: "при открытии файла .png с помощью блокнота" файлы .png это вам не текст. "как изменить .png с помощью блокнота" вам не как.

Comment: при открытии картинки в блокноте появляются символы я хотел бы добавить туда как то ссылку что бы при открытии кроме изначальных символов была моя ссылка .